# Однажды и т.д.

Tags: грамотная-речь

Однажды, дважды, трижды, четырежды... А как дальше?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут вообще-то два значения, но в обоих "однажды" не из этого ряда.

~1. Дважды, трижды, четырежды - по количеству раз, повторов. ("Я об этом говорил трижды") "Однажды" в этом значении почти не используется, только в значении "как-то раз",  "когда-то". Для однократного и повторов более четырех употребительных слов нет. Только - один раз, пять раз и т.д. Или пятикратно, шестикратно и т.д.

~2. Для обозначения умножения.
"Однажды" - тоже не отсюда.  Здесь правильно  - единожды.
Эти "термины" используются только при обозначении умножения - "дважды два" и т.д.  Дальше идет "пятью пять", "шестью шесть" и проч. Причина - в особом положении чисел от двух до четырех в русском языке. Подробности опускаю, это неподъёмная для данного форума тема.

Формы на -жды для чисел более пяти в современном языке совершенно неупотребительны.
Ранее окказионально, главным образом в ироничном употреблении, встечались "пятижды", "шестижды" и проч. Ещё в математическом жаргоне встречается "энежды" (тоже при умножении, вместо "N умножить на ...", "N раз по...").

(+)
Тут мне добавили информацию (@hvertous), что "однажды" может употребляться в первом (по моему списку) значении. Похоже, в этом я ошибся. В БТС Кузнецова, правда, примеры весьма неоднозначные, но тем не менее. Это не ломает никаким образом мой ответ по сути, вопрос вообще не об этом, но само по себе заслуживает внимания. Навскидку и на мой вкус: и у Кузнецова, и у Достоевского правильнее бы использовать "единожды". Но это обсуждается.

Comment: по поводу пункта 1 - "однажды" может спокойно использоваться в значении "один раз", и часто используется, особенно, в литературе.

Comment: @hvertous Пример можете привести? Без примера не верю.

Comment: `А не слыхали ли вы хоть однажды, что денег было промотано ... не три тысячи, а меньше?`, `Однажды слышали от него наедине, или неоднократно?` Достоевский, "Братья Карамазовы"

Comment: @hvertous спасибо. Я дополню ответ, если для меня что-то прояснится.